# Problem with time when I navigate in my nextjs project

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have a doubt in my nextjs project.

I added a new route inside my header calls `/files` and I don't know why takes a long time to load the data when I want to return to the home.

I console.log the request I and notice calls to my API and my INDEX twice, but I'm not sure if it's a problem.

The endpoint with the data is a little slow, but I believe that if I call it inside my `pages/index` getInitialProps, the data it's loaded in server at the beginning, I am right? and if I am right why is it taking so long to show me the data again?

Here is my code!

Header

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Header extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" bg="light" variant="light">
            <Navbar.Toggle
              aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav"
              style={{ outline: "0", display: 'none' }}
            />
            <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
              <Nav className="mr-auto"></Nav>
              <Nav>
                <Link href="/" passHref>
                  <Nav.Link>
                    Home
                  </Nav.Link>
                </Link>
                <Link href="/files" passHref>
                  <Nav.Link>
                    Files
                  </Nav.Link>
                </Link>
              </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Header;
```

pages/index

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

/* Others */
import Error from "./_error";
import { getDataLatestEvents } from "../helper/api";

/* Components */
import MyComponent from "../components/MyComponent";

/* Bootstrap Components */
import Row from "react-bootstrap/Row";


const Index = props => {
  console.log('index*************')
  const [contentData, setData] = useState([]);
  const res = props.data.data.data;  

  useEffect(() => {
    setData(res);
  }, [props]);

  if (props.statusCode !== 200) {
    return <Error statusCode={props.statusCode} />;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Row>
        <StyledContainer>
          <MyComponent
            data={contentData}
          />
        </StyledContainer>
      </Row>
    </>
  );
};

Index.getInitialProps = async ({ res }) => {
  try {
    let req = await getDataLatestEvents();
    return { data: req, statusCode: 200 };
  } catch (e) {
    res.statusCode = 503;
    console.log(`error /pages/index: ${e}`);
    return { data: null, statusCode: 503 };
  }
};

export default Index;
```

helper/api

```
import fetch from "isomorphic-unfetch";
const BASE_URL = "https://myendpoint/api";


export async function getDataLatestEvents() {
  const res = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/eventos?latest`);
  let data = await res.json();
  console.log('API*************')
  return { data: data};
}
```

Comment: Have you tried clicking on the network tab in Chrome to see what's taking so long to load? Also, seeing two responses in the console is a problem. You may have some code somewhere that needs looking at to fix this.

Comment: Yes, I checked in Network and the endpoint of `getDataLatestEvents` is the problem... Anyway I don 't know the console.log issue...I already checkit and I can 't find the problem...

Answer (score 4):

This sort of delay is often encountered when using `next dev` (via `yarn dev` or `npm dev`). This is because when using yarn dev, page is rebuild every time it is requested. So when you navigate back to the index page, Next.js first rebuild that page for you and then it is served. That's why there is a delay.

You should not find similar delay in production (when using `next build` and then `next start`)

## Edit

[getInitialProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps) enables server-side rendering in a page. In case you don't need to fetch any data every time the request is sent or page is reloaded, use `getStaticProps` instead.

Comment: It still delay around 1 seconds after `next build` and `next start`. Possible is server problem?

Comment: [getInitialProps][1] enables server-side rendering in a page. In case you don't need to fetch any data every time the request is sent or page is reloaded, use `getStaticProps` instead.

Comment: Exactly what I needed to hear. The prod builds are blazing fast!